# Why are users paged in a seemingly strange number? Magic "36"

Tags: feature-request, support

I've never got this and it's always bugged me when trying to count user pages. Maybe it's my OCD again and numbers have to be round?

It doesn't seem to make sense why Users are paged in batches of 36? Is 36 some magic number that I've not heard about? Maybe it's somen *super-secret-optimised-awesomeness* number?

Surely rounding to either 30 or 40 makes more sense? It's much easier to count too :).

Comment: 36 is a square. And a triangular number. The smallest such larger than 1, which would be a too small page size.

Comment: @DanielFischer Since when did page sizes come in triangles? :)

Comment: I guess it is just the maximum number of flairs that you can put on that page using SO layout size.

Comment: @DanielFischer, it is even better, it is the lowest product of two different squares greater that 1: 9 x 4.

Comment: @mattytommo That's not about the size. Two triangles a diamond make, honour the moderators.

Comment: @DanielFischer Then why not 72? That'd be 2 x triangles = a diamond ;)

Comment: Too large, the page size is too small for 72.

Comment: @DanielFischer Suggesting 72 has magically made me a mod look --->♦

Comment: If I had to hazard a guess, it's because the Users page was designed by a developer using the resolution 1280x1024, or it was determined that 1280x1024 was the most common developer resolution. The User list fits perfectly in my browser window, allowing me to see all the users at once. 9 rows of users x 4 columns = 36

Comment: @Rachel that's not really a valid excuse for choosing the number... It is nice, but people don't count by 36 easily... The developer could have just shrunk the height of a row (padding) and add a new row to make it a nice 40...

Comment: If I recall my geometry class correctly, a quadrilateral has 3 branches: parallelogram, kite(?), and trapezoid. The kite branches to a diamond while a parallelogram branches to something and a rectangle. Those two then "branch" into a square. So two triangles making a square _or_ a diamond doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ColeJohnson Trust me, you don't want to suggest to a UI developer that they simply reduce their padding so you can display a "nicer" number of objects. They can be very fussy about the margin and padding of elements - after all that's their job :) But honestly, nobody probably thought twice about it.

Comment: @Rachel being a UI developer, I at least look at things from the user standpoint and would reduce it if the math still came out nice (i.e. no half pixels)

Comment: Users used to be paged in 7 rows of 5, 8 rows of 4 probably seemed like a reasonable transition once the new layout required more horizontal space per user. Now, if you want to know why it used to be 35 per page, well...we don't talk about that.

Comment: @Tim pleeeezeee!